# How to fill a contour plot using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

I have the following code to create a contour plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

vector1 <- c(0,1,4,9,11,18)
vector2 <- c(1,5,7,9,14,16,17,20,40)
theme_bw()
result <- matrix(0, nrow = length(vector1), ncol = length(vector2))
for (i in seq_len(length(vector1))) {
  for (j in seq_len(length(vector2))) {
    result[i,j] <- 1 + (vector2[j] * (vector1[i]))
  }
}
rownames(result) <- vector1
colnames(result) <- vector2
as.data.frame(result) %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  gather(key, value, -rowname) %>%
  mutate(key = as.numeric(key), 
         rowname = as.numeric(rowname)) %>%

  ggplot() +
  geom_contour(aes(x = rowname, y = key, z = value))
```

[image: This is the result]

But I'd like to have something like that:

[image]

How can I fill the contour plot in `R` to have a plot like the colorful example?

Comment: try ```geom_density_2d``` https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_density_2d.html